# Blocking Windows Phone WebBrowser control from viewing my site?

Tags: php, windows-phone-8

I have found out that someone is selling an app that is directly using a WebBrowser/WebView to access a site that I wrote. I do not want this person making money off of my app, and the website is getting a bad reputation because people think I am trying to charge for this site.

Are there any Windows Phone WebView specific request headers I can block? I am running php and was planning on blocking access via the request headers.

Thank you!

Comment: unlikely that you would not end up blocking legit viewers

Answer (score 1):

Best to contact microsoft directly and report the app.

Answer (score 1):

Checking request headers is what I would do. That's simple to say, but how to do it depends on a lot of things. Need more info: Is your site intended for use in a regular browser, or do you also wrap it in an app?

...Tom

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want users to ONLY be able to access from their browser, not an app. I do not plan on making a Windows App at for this. I was wondering if any Windows app developers knew if there was different headers, as I do not have a Windows device myself.